# How to Use C++ Libraries with Livecode

Tags: livecode

I am looking to use the pHash.org libraries with Livecode for an academic project of mine. What are the steps to getting Livecode to talk to a C++ Library?

Most of my code is in Livecode except for image matching algorithms which pHash provides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two externals sdk's but they are fairly poorly documented. The best documented one is what is currently the iOS Externals SDK and will evolve into the modules sdk as the engine is refactored: http://livecode.com/developers/guides/externals/

For the older SDK the best thing to do is to look at some open source examples because I believe the old tutorials are no longer on RunRev's website. There are several in the LiveCode repo at:
http://github.com/runrev/livecode

I have a couple at:
http://github.com/montegoulding/mergJSON
http://github.com/montegoulding/mergMarkdown

There is also one here:
https://github.com/trevordevore/SSH-External-for-LiveCode